# I want to find the attribute of an object inside object in python

Tags: python, indexing, attributes, gs1-ai-syntax

So I'm trying to find all the values of ai = '' in the below given library for gs1. To access that it already has the command:

**result = biip.parse("010703206980498815210526100329")
result.gs1_message.element_strings**

for ex in the below code, I'd like to get all the values where **ai = '01', ai ='15' and ai ='10'.**
After finding these values, I need to make condition for each one of them like:
if ai ='01': then something.

But my main concern is how can I access it since its inside GS1ElementString, which is inside ai=GS1ApplicationIdentifier, but I don't want to get this value as here ai = is a string. I need values after that bracket where ai = '01' and then the same for the remaining three GS1ElementString.

[

```
[**GS1ElementString**(
    ai=GS1ApplicationIdentifier(
        **ai='01'**,
        description='Global Trade Item Number (GTIN)',
        data_title='GTIN',
        fnc1_required=False,
        format='N2+N14',
    ),

    value='07032069804988',
    pattern_groups=['07032069804988'],
    gln=None,
    gtin=Gtin(
        value='07032069804988',
        format=GtinFormat.GTIN_13,
        prefix=GS1Prefix(value='703', usage='GS1 Norway'),
        payload='703206980498',
        check_digit=8,
        packaging_level=None,
    ),

    sscc=None,
    date=None,
    decimal=None,
    money=None,
),

**GS1ElementString**(
    ai=GS1ApplicationIdentifier(
        **ai='15'**,
        description='Best before date (YYMMDD)',
        data_title='BEST BEFORE or BEST BY',
        fnc1_required=False,
        format='N2+N6',
    ),

    value='210526',
    pattern_groups=['210526'],
    gln=None,
    gtin=None,
    sscc=None,
    date=datetime.date(2021, 5, 26),
    decimal=None,
    money=None,
),

**GS1ElementString**(
    ai=GS1ApplicationIdentifier(
        **ai='10'**,
        description='Batch or lot number',
        data_title='BATCH/LOT',
        fnc1_required=True,
        format='N2+X..20'
    ),

    value='0329',
    pattern_groups=['0329'],
    gln=None,
    gtin=None,
    sscc=None,
    date=None,
    decimal=None,
    money=None,
),]
```

Here is the link to the biip library documentation for a better understanding: **https://biip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart/**
It under **Product IDs, expiration dates, and lot numbers**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to do it reading the hovering over the `GS1ApplicationIdentifier` function and reading the documentation on PyCharm.

Using this:

```
i = str(GS1ApplicationIdentifier.extract("01"))
s = ai[1:-1]
```

```
--> (01)
--> 01
```

I easily get the `ai` value that I'm interested in. And then using slicing I removed the brackets.

Comment: I think you should mark this answer as answering own question, or it's actually a comment. A bit against SO rules in such case.